# JavaScript not loaded on AJAX call at WooCommerce Cart page

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using `woocommerce_after_shipping_rate` hook to add my codes, some PHP, some JS. On normal page load, all of my codes are loaded perfectly. But when I add/remove items from cart, or update my address at shipping calculator, which caused an update at the available shipping methods (using AJAX), my JS codes are not loaded.

Probably this is just a very basic thing I missed. Here's a simple version of my code:

```
function abc( $method, $index ) {

    echo "This loaded on AJAX just fine";

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "var a = 'This is NOT loaded on AJAX call, along with the tags above and below this';";
    echo "</script>";

    echo "This also loaded on AJAX just fine";

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'abc', 10, 2 );
```

In case anyone wondered, my JS code is to put some variables which my JS function at the page header needs. The variables are based on the available shipping method currently loaded.

What I hope can be achieved is for my JS code to also be loaded on AJAX.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "This is NOT loaded on AJAX call"? Is the `<script>` tag not present in the response? Is it present, but not added to the DOM? Or is it present, added to the dom, but just not executed?

Comment: Also, not related to the question, but you forgot a `}`

Comment: @jrswgtr Yes, those 3 lines are not present when the AJAX finished loading. Starting from the <script type='text/javascript'> until </script>. Above and below those 3 lines loaded just fine. And yes, I missed a }, thanks.

Comment: Maybe those lines are sent to the browser, but you can't see them because there are not added to the DOM, log the output to console, I'm almost sure that script tags will be there.

Comment: @Triby Hey, you're right! I checked at the Response Payload at Network tab, the `<script type='text/javascript'>` is there, along with the contents. I don't understand, what's going on here? Why isn't it loaded to the DOM??

Comment: Javascript can't be executed just adding tags from an AJAX call, you need to find another way. Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably more of a "hack" instead of an answer.

Basically the problem was anything using `<script>` tag was not loaded to the DOM (but actually sent to the browser from the server). So I change `<script>` into `<div style='display:none;'>` and keep the content as is (still filled with JS).

```
function abc( $method, $index ) {

    echo "This loaded on AJAX just fine";

    echo "<div class='response-div' style='display:none;'>";
    echo "var a = 'This is where you echo all your JS';";
    echo "</div>";

    echo "This also loaded on AJAX just fine";

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'abc', 10, 2 );
```

And then on `window.load` and `document.ajaxComplete`, I copy the innerHTML from the `<div>` and create a new `<script>` element to **REPLACE** the `<div>`, containing the same innerHTML.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20584396/10069015 has the replacement function, but for the whole page. I just had to modify it to adjust to my needs.

As stupid as this sound, it works. Mind you, my goal is only to write some global JS variables, not actually executing a JS function. So I don't know whether this method will work if you want to do that.